# What Windows SHARED web host supports Microsoft Chart Controls?

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, .net

With GoDaddy "[This service will not work on a Shared Hosting server. You will need to purchase a Dedicated or Virtual Dedicated Server.](http://community.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/microsoft-char-controls-work-here/)"

They want [$29.99/month](http://www.godaddy.com/hosting/virtual-dedicated-servers.aspx?ci=9013).

How can I get chart controls working for more a affordable price, like the usual 4.99/month

Thank You.

Anyone tried [WebWiz](http://www.webwiz.co.uk/web-hosting/windows-web-hosting.htm) /or [these](http://www.hostsearch.com/windows_web_hosting.asp),...  ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a blog post that looks like it lists a possible solution to the problem you have:

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-chart-control-on-shared-hosting-environment-chartimagehandler-parser-error-problem-solution.

Starting with .Net 4.0, the chart controls are actually part of the .Net framework.